# How can you determine which process scheduler is being used?

Tags: linux, kernel, process, scheduling

I.e. is it the O(1) scheduler, the CFS scheduler, or an older one?

Comment: Which OS are you asking about?

Comment: I assume you're talking about Linux? I don't think there's any other unix variant with these scheduler names.

Comment: It's a linux variant: RHEL

Answer (score 3):

You can call `sched_getscheduler(process_pid)` to determine the scheduling policy for a process.

If `/sys/kernel/uids` exists, you have CFS.   Or you could try

```
[[ -n $(awk '$3 == "load_balance_fair" {print;}' < /proc/kallsyms) ]] && 
  echo CFS
```

I'm not sure how you could distinguish the O(1) scheduler from other obsolete schedulers.   You could use the kernel version I suppose, but since distributions applied patches to their shipped kernels, this will be unreliable.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but it looks like the return value from [`sched_getscheduler`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_getscheduler.2.html) doesn't tell you which process scheduler is being used, just what scheduling policy is being used for the current process (essentially: normal/batch/realtime/low priority).

Comment: Yes.   That's why the second and following sentences of my answer are there!

Answer (score 0):

The scheduler of a process can be defined by the programmer, using this funcion
man sched_setscheduler

to see the scheduler uses by a process you can use the top command

for change the scheduler of a procces chrt

Comment: The `sched_setscheduler` allows a program to define parameters for the scheduler. It is not selecting which scheduler O(1) or CFS the linux is using. Nowadays, since kernel 2.6.23, the official kernel uses the CFS scheduler --  You may check http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html